# In the virtual environment the package is not the virtual environment package

Tags: python, virtualenv

Why in the virtual environment, I check pip3, it is not the venv location:

```
(venv) MacBook-Pro:Qiyun02 ldl$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

You see its location is :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Why its not under the venv:

```
pwd
/Users/denghai/Desktop/Test/Project/Qi/venv
```

Comment: did you installed using sudo?

Comment: If your current `python` env variable is located at the correct location (in the venv), just use `python -m pip` and save yourself some time.

Comment: Pip is cross-compat.  In a venv, pip is just `pip`.  Generally, `pip2` and `pip3` are just conveniences for system interpreters.

Comment: @wim But, if I have a project, I want to use the python3 and pip3, how about it? whether it is use the system interpreter? or, whether we can install pip3 and python3 in venv?

Comment: What I'm saying is `pip` and `pip3` are the same thing.  Make a symlink if you really want to call it `pip3`.

Comment: I see, so, only the other packages are in the venv, alright?